# alternative truncate cmd on AIX IBM Server

Tags: unix, websphere, aix, truncate

I want to purge a file without deleting it. I wanted to use the **truncate** command but unfortunately it is not installed on **AIX IBM** and setting up a package manager is too difficult on this operating system.
Do you have an alternative for **truncate** cmd ? or any idea how to purge a file ?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the redirection operator with no command to truncate a file

```
$ echo abc > file; ls -l file; > file; ls -l file
-rw-r--r--  1 covener  wheel  4 Feb 15 07:16 file
-rw-r--r--  1 covener  wheel  0 Feb 15 07:16 file
```